# Enable submit button when select checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have try a few examples of enable the submit button when checkbox is selected but i'm getting nowhere. Below is one of my attempts, where the submit button is disabled until the checkbox is selected. Please let me know what am i missing.

```js
function checked(sub1) {
  var myLayer = document.getElementById(sub1);
  var input = myLayer.childNodes[0];
  if (input.checked == true) {
    myLayer.disabled = "";
  } else {
    myLayer.disabled = "disabled";
  }
}
```

```html
<p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx " onchange="checked('sub1')" />
</p>

<p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1" disabled="disabled" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nobody has explained *why* your code isn't working.

For one, you aren't selecting the `input` checkbox element properly. It is not a child node of the button element. You could either get a reference to the checkbox by passing `this` in the `onchange` event, or you could pass the `event` object and access the checkbox element through the `event.target` property:

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx " onchange="isChecked(this, 'sub1')" />
```

Then you can access a reference to the checkbox element that fired on the change event:

```
function isChecked(checkbox, sub1) {
  // checkbox
}
```

After changing a couple things, it would work as expected:

```
function isChecked(checkbox, sub1) {
    var button = document.getElementById(sub1);

    if (checkbox.checked === true) {
        button.disabled = "";
    } else {
        button.disabled = "disabled";
    }
}
```

However, you can simplify the code and rewrite it to:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/1660ju5t/)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx " onchange="isChecked(this, 'sub1')" />
```

```
function isChecked(checkbox, sub1) {
    document.getElementById(sub1).disabled = !checkbox.checked;
}
```

As a side note, I would highly suggest using unobtrusive JavaScript and add an event listener to the element in order to avoid inline `onchange` events:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/uskeh25n/)

```
document.getElementById('termsChkbx').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  document.getElementById('sub1').disabled = !e.target.checked;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx " onchange="isChecked(this,'sub1')"/></p>
 <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1" disabled="disabled"/></p>
```

JS

```
function isChecked(chk,sub1) {
    var myLayer = document.getElementById(sub1);
    if (chk.checked == true) {
        myLayer.disabled = false;
    } else {
        myLayer.disabled = true;
    };
}
```

<kbd>**[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/kkt651gOrLdCIDKMA33G?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete code

```
<p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
    <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx " onclick="change_button(this,'sub1')"/>
</p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1" disabled="disabled"/></p>

<script type = "text/javascript">
function change_button(checkbx,button_id) {
    var btn = document.getElementById(button_id);
    if (checkbx.checked == true) {
        btn.disabled = "";
    } else {
        btn.disabled = "disabled";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this JQuery function

```
$(function() {
    $('#termsChkbx').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#sub1').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#sub1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

**Example**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
       <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" /></p>
    
       <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1" disabled="disabled"/></p>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#termsChkbx').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#sub1').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#sub1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The major problem can be easily checked by using the browser's debug console. There you can immediately see an exception.

**Try this:**

Html:

```
<p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
    <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" onchange="checked('sub1', this.checked);" />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1" disabled="disabled" />
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checked(sub1, checkedState) {
    document.getElementById(sub1, this).disabled = !checkedState;
}
```

But be aware, that this code snippet is not best practice. It just solves your current problem without using libraries like jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

While your problem has been solved, there is no need for JavaScript here.
This can be done with pure CSS/HTML:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ input[type="submit"]{
  pointer-events: none;
  tab-index: -1;
  color: graytext;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="this.value='clicked';"/>
```

I've used the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) pseudo-class to detect when a check-box isn't ticked as this is [w3c's recommended approach](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#checked). I wasn't sure where (in HTML) the check box is in relevance to the button, so I used the tilde ([`~` general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)) to find the button. If the check-box is immediately before the button I would recommend using the [adjacent sibling selector `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) instead.

However if you have multiple check-boxes and you only want one check-box to toggle the button's state then using the [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type) pseudo class or an `id` may be more appropriate:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:nth-of-type(2):not(:checked) ~ input[type="submit"]{
  pointer-events: none;
  tab-index: -1;
  color: graytext;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="this.value='clicked';"/>
```

Otherwise all the check-boxes will be 'required' for the button to become click-able:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ input[type="submit"]{
  pointer-events: none;
  tab-index: -1;
  color: graytext;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="this.value='clicked';"/>
```