# Change a bootstrap button from disabled to active based on checkbox

Tags: javascript

I want to use this checkbox function that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973512/enable-submit-button-when-select-checkbox) however in my existing page I use bootstrap button that have the following form.

```
  <p style="color: #FFFFFF">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx " onclick="change_button(this,'sub1')"/>
  </p>
  <a class="btn btn-light btn-xl disabled" href="randomlink.com">Download Now</a>
```

What are the modifications I should make in the function or the button to turn it to enabled, after the user has clicked on the checkbox?
PS: I include the referenced function below.

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    function change_button(checkbx,button_id) {
        var btn = document.getElementById(button_id);
        if (checkbx.checked == true) {
            btn.disabled = "";
        } else {
            btn.disabled = "disabled";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Use a `<button>` instead of a `<a>` (link). You cannot disable links, only buttons.

Comment: In this specific case you have to give your button the ID 'sub1' in the DOM, because `change_button()` expects the button ID as the second parameter in order to find it in the DOM: `<a id="sub1" class="btn btn-light btn-xl disabled" href="randomlink.com">Download Now</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a runnable example based on your code. I've adapted your example with the following things:

- The `<a>` tag must be a `<button>` in order to disable it. The anchor tag does not have a disabled attribute.
- The button must be initially disabled (therefore the added `disabled` attribute).
- You are passing an ID as an argument to the function. This ID must be equal to the button's ID. So, I added it as an attribute to the button.
- I've removed the `disabled` class from the button, as it is not necessary, when there is an attribute `disabled`.
- The button must submit a form, so you can either wrap it in a `<form>` or use a JavaScript click listener on the button. I've used the 2nd option in the solution below.

```js
function change_button(checkbx,button_id) {
  var btn = document.getElementById(button_id);
  if (checkbx.checked == true) {
    btn.disabled = "";
  } else {
    btn.disabled = "disabled";
  }
}

function submit() {
  window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #555 !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p style="color: #FFFFFF">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" onclick="change_button(this, 'sub1')"/>
</p>
<button disabled id="sub1" class="btn btn-light btn-xl" onclick="submit()">Download Now</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sing a button like below. Wrap your `<a>` tag inside a `<button>` tag. Anchor tag does not have disabled property, but `button` have.

In order to disable the anchor tag, you have to clear the href manually.

```js
function change_button(checkbx,button_id) {
    var btn = document.getElementById(button_id);
    if (checkbx.checked == true) {
        btn.disabled = false;
        btn.children[0].href = "randomlink.com";
    } else {
        btn.disabled = true;
        btn.children[0].href = "javascript: void(0)";
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <p style="color: #FFFFFF">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
<input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx " onclick="change_button(this,'sub1')"/>
</p>
<button class="btn btn-light btn-xl" disabled id="sub1">
  <a>Download Now</a>
</button>
```

Comment: The link always works, also when the button is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `checked` to see if the checkbox is ticked or not and then add an id for your button as well so you can use the [classList()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) JavaScript property to toggle the `disable` class name based on the status of the checkbox.

Also, avoid using inline scripts like `onclick` and use an event listener in your JavaScript itself like this:

```js
let chkBox = document.getElementById("termsChkbx");
let btn = document.getElementById("someBtn");

chkBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(this.checked == true) {
    btn.classList.remove("disabled");
  } else {
    btn.classList.add("disabled");
  }
});
```

```css
body {background-color: #000 !important;}
```

```html
<!-- Botstrap CSS File --><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><!-- Botstrap CSS File -->

<p>I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx"/>
</p>

<a id ="someBtn" class="btn btn-light btn-xl disabled" href="randomlink.com">Download Now</a>
```

---

JSFiddle with the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/k3po4zfa/1/

Answer (score 0):

To stop clicking, in addition to adding the disabled class, add this to your css:

pointer-events: none;

It won't stop people from tabbing to the button and hitting space or enter, but it will stop them from clicking